# Configure apache web server not to log access

Tags: apache-2.2, logging

How can I configure the apache web server such that it does not log any access to the server?

Comment: What web server?

Comment: tag says it's apache .)

Comment: Note that this is *really* not recommended... I can't imagine a really good reason for shutting off logging entirely. But if you can afford to have bad things happen to the server and never know about it, then I guess it's not such a big deal.

Comment: One situation where disabling all logging may be desirable is when running on an embedded platform with a flash card.  There it is important to eliminate ALL unnecessary writes to flash.  Of course, in that situation, you'd probably want to run something a little lighter than Apache anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace CustomLog entries with:

```
CustomLog /dev/null combined
```

and ErrorLog entries with:

```
ErrorLog /dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

you should remove CustomLog / AccessLog / ErrorLog entries for whatever reason you don't want it to log any access, errors or custom info.

Comment: This won't work because at least with ErrorLog the default value "logs/error_log" will jump in if you do not override it in your configuration.